# Gradle user manual example failure

Tags: gradle, exception, build, task, manual

Trying to follow official **gradle 6.3** user manual I faced example that doesn't work.
build.gradle:

```
project('projectA') {
  task taskX {
    dependsOn ':projectB:taskY'
    doLast {
      println 'taskX'
    }
  }
}

project('projectB') {
  task taskY {
    doLast {
      println 'taskY'
    }
  }
}
```

But if I run `gradle -q taskX` I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '[path_to_gradle_file]/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'dependency'.
> Project with path 'projectA' could not be found in root project 'dependency'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the multi-project gradle script for this case it is required to have `settings.gradle` with:

```
include 'projectA', 'projectB'
```